# How to return a non static field from a static method in Dart

Tags: dart

**Code:**

```
class Rates {
  static double get value => _value; // error

  // Only constructor should set this value
  final double _value;

  Rates(this._value);
}

void main() {
  // This is how I want to use value
  final value = Rates.value;
}
```

I have mentioned what I need in comments section of the code, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  Do you want `Rates.value` to return the last value that a `Rates` instance was constructed with?  Are you trying to implement a singleton?

Comment: @jamesdlin Actually I want `Rates` to hold a single value, and that value should only be initialised in constructor, plus I also want to use that value directly like `Rates.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually I want `Rates` to hold a single value, and that value should only be initialised in constructor, plus I also want to use that value directly like `Rates.value`.

I still don't fully understand what you're trying to do nor why you'd want such a design (why bother with a class and a constructor at all?), but:

```dart
class Rates {
  static double get value => _value;

  static double _value;

  Rates(double value) {
    // Allow _value to be set only once.  Further attempts will be ignored.
    _value ??= value;
  }
}

void main() {
  Rates(42.0);

  final value = Rates.value;
}
```

As currently written, there isn't any point to having the `Rates` constructor.  It'd be simpler and less unusual to have a setter to initialize the value:

```dart
class Rates {
  static double get value => _value;
  static set value(double value) => _value ??= value;

  static double _value;
}
```

or just make it freestanding with no class:

```dart
double get rateValue => _rateValue;
set rateValue(double value) => _rateValue ??= value;

double _rateValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is impossible, and it doesn't even make sense.

An *instance field*, like `_value`, exists on each instance of the class.
A static method, like the `value` getter, does not have access to any instance.

It's like being asked for the first word of the book ... without saying which book.

Comment: I got that sir, but the use case I am trying to achieve is this, "I want `Rates` to hold a single value, and that value should only be initialised/changed in constructor, plus I also want to use that value directly like `Rates.value`", is it possible sir?

Comment: Not as `Rates` is written, with `_value` being an instance member. You can do what @jamesdlin said, but there is no reason to use a constructor then.